# sorting edges and vertice of a graph

Tags: graph, julia, edges

let

```
G=DiMultigraph(4)
 add_edge!(G,2,4)
 add_edge!(G,4,1)
 add_edge!(G,4,1)
 add_edge!(G,1,3)
 add_edge!(G,1,3)
 add_edge!(G,2,3)
```

When I run

```
e=edges(G)
e1=collect(e)
```

I got

```
 Multiple edge 1 => 3 with multiplicity 2
 Multiple edge 2 => 3 with multiplicity 1
 Multiple edge 2 => 4 with multiplicity 1
 Multiple edge 4 => 1 with multiplicity 2
```

What I want to have is the non sorted list

```
 Multiple edge 2 => 4 with multiplicity 1
 Multiple edge 4 => 1 with multiplicity 2
 Multiple edge 1 => 3 with multiplicity 1
 Multiple edge 2 => 3 with multiplicity 1
```

it seems like there is  a code for that [here](https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/GraphIO.jl/blob/master/src/Edgelist/Edgelist.jl) but I don't really understand it.

Comment: why do you think your second list is sorted? It looks to be unsorted to me. Perhaps it would help if you could explain what sorting order you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the edges in the order you inserted them. To do that, you need to have a key to sort by.  Here is one way:

```
edgevector = [[2,4], [4,1], [4,1],[1,3],[1,3],[2,3]]
G = DiMultigraph(4)
for edg in edgevector
    add_edge!(G, edg[1], edg[2])
end

e = edges(G)
e1 = sort!(collect(e), by = edg -> findfirst(==([edg.src, edg.dst]), edgevector))
```